# Replicate previous value in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Dataframe with a `column A` that start with zero, than there are same numbers interspersed with zeros.
I need a `column C` where:

- First rows are equal to zero till to first number in `column A`
- Zero where numbers are present in `column A`
- Same previous number of `column A` till to next one

The result should be like below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0], columns=['A'])
df['B'] = ([0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 6, 6])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do:

```
where = df['A'].ne(0)
df['B'] = df['A'].where(where).ffill().mask(where, 0)
```